# Remainimg volume in sphere after cylindrical hole is drilled out from it

Tags: integration

Calculate volume remaining after a cylinder of  diameter $a$  pierces a sphere of  radius $a$ with offset $c$. We may find interesting results in special cases.

I know when $c = 0$ (central hole in sphere)  and $ c=a/2 $ ( Viviani).

EDIT1: One motivation for post is Struik's comment in his text book page 10, Chap 1, that area and volume outside of cylinder is *rational* in a.

Comment: The interesting result is that it only depends on the height of the remaining ring. What have you done so far? This is a standard third-semester calculus assignment to be solved using polar coordinates and geometrical reasoning.

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napkin_ring_problem) may be of help

Comment: @AlexR: Want to see if result is already available when $ c\ne  0$ towards generalization.For Viviani case it depends only on $a$ anyhow.

Comment: @Narasimham Since the Viviani case only has $a$ as a variable, this is hardly surprising. I told you a more general result: It's independent of $a$ and $c$ if you are given the remaining height $h$.

Comment: @AlexR:I too think so; regarding Struik's rationality comment in Viviani situation whether something more is here?